# Закрыть baloon placemark по клику на карту а не на крестик самого baloon в react-yandex-map

Tags: reactjs, yandex-maps-api

Вот код кому интересно и есть время помочь
https://codesandbox.io/s/l7oqnz7mml

Answer (score 1):

Не знаю, как закрыть balloon корректно через API, но нашёл решение, которое работает в вашем случае:

```
function closeCurrentBalloon() {
  let close = document.querySelector('ymaps[class$="-balloon__close-button"]');
  if (close != null) {
    close.click();
  }
}

function App() {
  return (
    <div className="App">
      <YMaps>
        <Map state={mapState} onClick={closeCurrentBalloon}>
          ...
        </Map>
      </YMaps>
    </div>
  );
}
```

Для наглядности: https://codesandbox.io/s/react-yandex-maps-issue-101-9s5q1

Comment: myMap.events.add('click', function (e) {  

myPlacemark.balloon.close();  

});

Comment: Но я наверно плохо работаю с документацией и не получается перенести в React

Comment: [https://yandex.ru/blog/mapsapi/32290]

Comment: А предложенный мной ранее вариант у вас работает? https://codesandbox.io/s/react-yandex-maps-issue-101-9s5q1

Comment: да, но есть возможность через api сделать... только что-то не выходит перенести благополучно в React

Answer (score 0):

В реакте нужно получить instanceRef компонента YMap и Placemark, после навесить событие при клике на карту для закрытия балуна:

```
const [map, setMap] = useState();
const [placemark, setPlacemark] = useState();

useEffect(() => {
    if (!map || !placemark) {
        return;
    }

    map.events.add('click', () => placemark.balloon.close());
}, [map, placemark]);

<YMaps query={{load: 'package.full'}}>
    <YMap
        instanceRef={setMap}
        {...yMapProps}
    >
        <Placemark
            instanceRef={setPlacemark}
            {...yMapPlacemarkProps}
        >
    </YMap>
</YMaps>
```